# How to deal with different margins?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, styled-components

I am currently working on one project, and I got stuck on a styling problem. I am using react.js with styled-components. I have different invoice cards inside the list, and the content of each of them depends on data, which comes from JSON. My problem is with spacing, as the content of card elements can differ, I can not assign a fixed margin to them; if I do it, I get something like this [Link to the image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xYu2.png) instead of this [what it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba14r.png). As you can see in the design, they should be at the same level. When I add min-width to the id, name and date, I have another spacing problem between name and price.
This is my code in this component.

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { ReactComponent as RightIcon } from "../../../images/icon-arrow-right.svg";
import data from "../data/invoices.json";

const InvoiceCardComponent = styled.li`
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1.6rem 3.2rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px -10px rgba(72, 84, 159, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.white};
  &:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 1.6rem;
  }
`;

const Id = styled.p`
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-right: 4.3rem;
`;

const HashTag = styled.span`
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.shipCove};
`;

const Date = styled.p`
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.baliHai};
  margin-right: 4.5rem;
`;

const Time = styled.time``;

const Name = styled.p`
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.baliHai};
`;

const Price = styled.p`
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  line-height: 2.4rem;
  margin-right: 4rem;
`;

const Status = styled.p`
  margin-right: 2rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.success};
  text-transform: capitalize;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.lightSuccess};
  min-width: 10.4rem;
  padding: 1.3rem 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
`;

const UserInfo = styled.div`
  display: flex;
`;

const PaymentInfo = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
`;

const StatusIcon = styled.span`
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 100%;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.success};
  margin-right: 8px;
`;

const InvoiceCard = () => {
  const renderInvoices = data.map((invoice) => {
    const date = new window.Date(invoice.paymentDue);
    const month = date.toLocaleString("en-US", { month: "short" });
    const day = date.getDate();
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const formattedTotal = invoice.total.toLocaleString("en-US", {
      currency: "GBP",
      style: "currency",
    });

    return (
      <InvoiceCardComponent key={invoice.id}>
        <UserInfo>
          <Id>
            <HashTag>#</HashTag>
            {invoice.id}
          </Id>
          <Date>
            <Time dateTime={invoice.paymentDue}>
              Due {day} {month} {year}
            </Time>
          </Date>
          <Name>{invoice.clientName}</Name>
        </UserInfo>
        <PaymentInfo>
          <Price>{formattedTotal}</Price>
          <Status>
            <StatusIcon></StatusIcon>
            {invoice.status}
          </Status>
          <RightIcon />
        </PaymentInfo>
      </InvoiceCardComponent>
    );
  });

  return <React.Fragment>{renderInvoices}</React.Fragment>;
};

export default InvoiceCard;
```

I will appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to explicitly set `width` for each column in each row.
Then in each column, you can do any kind of styling based on your need (`text-align`, `flex` with `justify-content`, etc), so all the cells in the same column have the same styles.

```css
.row-wrap {
  display: flex;
}
.col-wrap {
  background: red;
  margin: 2px;
}
.col1 {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: left;
}
.col2 {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}
.col3 {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: left;
}
.col4 {
  width: 400px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
      <div class="row-wrap">
        <div class="col-wrap col1">text</div>
        <div class="col-wrap col2">text</div>
        <div class="col-wrap col3">text</div>
        <div class="col-wrap col4">text</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row-wrap">
        <div class="col-wrap col1">
          longgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg text
        </div>
        <div class="col-wrap col2">text</div>
        <div class="col-wrap col3">text</div>
        <div class="col-wrap col4">text</div>
      </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, Cuong Vu, thank you for the time and effort that you put into explaining it to me . However, setting width explicitly is not a good practice for responsive websites, especially, where your content differs. So, this will not solve my problem but thank you anyway. 